# Catch a html tag value with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a div tag like

```
<div id="123" reference="r045">
```

Now I wanna save the value of the reference. I tried it with

```
var reference = document.getElementbyName("reference");
```

Didnt work. Any ideas?

Thanks :)

Comment: That's not element name, that's elements attribute...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var reference = document.getElementById("123").getAttribute("reference");
```

Comment: Great! Thanks buddy

Answer (score 7):

`getElementbyName` gets an element by its name.

The `reference` attribute:

- Is not a `name` attribute
- Is not valid HTML at all

So start by writing valid HTML:

```
<div id="123" data-reference="r045">
```

Then get a reference to that element:

```
const div = document.getElementById('123');
```

Then get the data from it using [the dataset API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset):

```
console.log(div.dataset.reference);
```

## Live demo

```js
const div = document.getElementById('123');
console.log(div.dataset.reference);
```

```html
<div id="123" data-reference="r045"></div>
```

Comment: I didn't know about the dataset API. Thank you for this great answer!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `document.querySelectorAll('[reference]')` if you have multiple `div` with same attribute.

```js
var reference = document.querySelectorAll('[reference]');
console.log(reference);
```

```html
<div id="123" reference="r045"></div>
```

But if you have only one `div` with `reference` attribute then use `querySelector`:

```js
var reference = document.querySelector('[reference]');
console.log(reference);
```

```html
<div id="123" reference="r045"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var x = document.getElementById("123").getAttribute("reference");
 console.log(x);
```

```html
<div id="123" reference="r045"></div>
```